# Why is %hd necessary in scanf?

Tags: c

I created a very simple progam whith a menu,
that take a value, then memorize it into the
local variable value, and finally with the 
second option the progam prints the value.

my question is:
Why does the program work only if I add an "h"
to the scanf parameter?
In other words: what kind of relation there is
between scanf() and my local int value variable?

thanks!

p.S. (I used Dev-C++ (GCC) to compile it. 
With Visual Studio it works)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {

    int value = 0;
    short choice = 0;

    do {
       printf("\nYour Choice ---> ");
       scanf("%d", &choice);  /* replace with "%hd" and it works */

       switch (choice) {
          case 1:
               printf("\nEnter a volue to store ");
               scanf("%d", &value);
               getchar();              
               printf("\nValue: %d", value);
               break;
          case 2:
               printf("\nValue: %d", value);            
               break;  
       }

    } while (choice < 3);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad text formatting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `scanf`, the "h" modifier indicates that it's reading a short integer, which your variable `choice` just happens to be. So the "%hd" is necessary to write only two bytes (on most machines) instead of the 4 bytes that "%d" writes.

For more info, see this [reference page on scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: hello, `%hd` works indeed but then, why do these [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications) and [cplusplus entry](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) make no mention of it whatsoever, actually stating that `%h` is to be used??

Answer (score 2):

The variable `choice` is of type `short` so that's why you need the `%h` specifier in scanf to read into it (in fact you don't need the `d` here). The `int` type just requires `%d`. See the notes on conversions [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/)

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is why because of this "h" missing, my program doesn't store the value into the int value variable?

Comment: @Mario: because scanf defines "%hd" to mean "read two bytes (on a 32-bit platform) and put it into a short int data type.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading into a short. The h is necessary because %d is the size of an int by default. See this [reference page on scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that `choice` is a `short`, which is (generally) 2 bytes long, while `%d` expects an integer, which is (generally) 4 bytes long… So the `scanf` clobbers whatever comes after `choice` on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

`choice` is a `short` and %d specifies an `int`.

When you specify %d, scanf has to assume that the associated argument is a pointer to an `int` sized block of memory, and will write an `int` to it.  When that happens it will likely be writing to data adjacent to but not part of `choice` and the results are undefined and probably not good!  If it works in one compiler and not another that is simply the nature of *undefined* behaviour!

In GCC -Wformat should give you a warning when you make this error.

Answer (score 1):

From the comp.lang.c FAQ:

- [Why doesn't the code `short int s; scanf("%d", &s);` work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfh.html)
- [Someone told me it was wrong to use `%lf` with `printf`. How can `printf` use `%f` for type `double`, if `scanf` requires `%lf`?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfvsprintf.html)

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is for reading an `int`, not a short. Your code never really "worked" -- it just appears that in this case you didn't notice any difference between what you wanted and the undefined behavior you got.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier for scanf to input a variable of type short is %hd. Hence you need to specify the correct modifier.

```
scanf("%d",&integer);  // For integer type
scanf("%hd",&short_int); // For short type
```

Hence it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon numeric padding, endian-ness, and other such issues, you may be storing either the upper or lower part of the input value into choice; you are storing the rest of the input value into memory that may or may not be being used for anything else.